# print the count value and count in jdbc

Tags: sql, jdbc

I'm writing a program where I need to count the values in a column rows. But while printing I need to print the count along with the value like below example.

```
AAA 5
BBB 2
CCC 8
DDD 4
EEE 5
```

But I'm now able to see only

```
5
2
8
4
5
```

Below is my code.

```
private static void getTheDetailedDataForRca() throws Exception {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl1");
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl);

        String queryString = "select count(Error) as Errors from [Quality Sheet$] group by Error";
        PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement(queryString);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("Errors"));
        }

    }
```

please let me know how can I get the above desired output in example.

I need this was as I've to make some key-value pairs and add it to my program.

Thanks

Comment: replace `count(Error)` with `Error, count(Error)` and adjust display code

Answer (score 2):

To flesh out @Lashane's comment, your aggregate query is not showing the grouping level, `Error` though you do employ the grouping. So simply add the grouping to `select` clause:

```
select Error, count(Error) as Errors from [Quality Sheet$] group by Error
```

And then in your print line, output both fields:

```
System.out.println(rs.getString("Error")+ " " +rs.getInt("Errors"));
```